# JDK install - no matching plugin

Tags: debian, installation, java

I'm trying to install JDK on my remote Debian box. I've been following the directions at [this page](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/Installing_Sun%27s_Java_environment_on_Debian_systems).

Problem is, the make-jpkg fails. Here's the output I get (plus the version of java-package I'm running:

```
:~/Desktop/Downloads$ fakeroot make-jpkg jdk-6u16-linux-i586.bin 

Creating temporary directory: /tmp/make-jpkg.BdyKSdDYXH

Loading plugins: blackdown-j2re.sh blackdown-j2sdk.sh common.sh ibm-j2re.sh ibm-j2sdk.sh j2re.sh j2sdk-doc.sh j2sdk.sh j2se.sh sun-j2re.sh sun-j2sdk-doc.sh sun-j2sdk.sh



Detected Debian build architecture: i386

Detected Debian GNU type: i486-linux-gnu



No matching plugin was found.

Removing temporary directory: done

:~/Desktop/Downloads$ apt-cache policy java-package | head -2java-package:

  Installed: 0.42
```

Any ideas why it's failing?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like  you are trying to build a newer version of the Sun jdk  than make-jpkg is configured for.  In the past when I've ran into this I've modified the plugin for make-jpkg.

In this case the correct plugin is probably "/usr/share/java-package/sun-j2sdk.sh".

1. Make a backup copy of the file in case you run into problems.
2. Open the file in your favorite editor.
3. Add the following to the case statement for your architecture (i386|i486-linux-gnu).  This was shamelessly copied from the sun-j2sdk.sh plugin on Ubuntu 9.04.

   ```
   "jdk-6u"[0-9][0-9]"-linux-i586.bin") # SUPPORTED
       j2se_version=1.6.0+update${archive_name:6:2}${revision}
       j2se_expected_min_size=130
       found=true
       ;;
   ```
4. Save the file.
5. Run make-jpkg as before.

If all goes well you, should now be able to install your shiney new java package.

Take care.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't be using make-jpkg any more. It was a temporary hack until Debian could distribute the JDK itself. The article you linked to is four years old. Install sun-java6-jdk package instead. Lenny has 6u12. If you really need 6u16, it is available in sid.

http://packages.debian.org/lenny/sun-java6-jdk

Comment: They've since been removed: http://sylvestre.ledru.info/blog/sylvestre/2011/10/25/removal_of_sun_java6_from_debian

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following as a regular user:

```
DEB_BUILD_GNU_TYPE=i386-linux fakeroot make-jpkg jdk-6u16-linux-i586.bin
```

And afterwards running the command that failed (hopefully it works this time).